# fancytree - wide extension with checkbox option change

Tags: fancytree

I have raised an issue related to the fancytree wide extension: https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/issues/782

Problem: 
When changing the fancytree checkbox option, via some event- such us click of the button, the padding is not set right (press button several times): 
https://jsfiddle.net/hafasek/9038m2c8/

```
$("#tree").fancytree({
  ...      
  checkbox: true, //checkbox option
  ...

  // in some event:
  var checkbox = $("#tree").fancytree("option", "checkbox");
  $("#tree").fancytree("option", "checkbox", !checkbox); //enable/disable checkbox option
```

Does anyone have a workaround idea for not breaking padding when enabling/disabling checkbox option?

Answer (score 0):

ext-wide currently (v2.24.0) creates CSS rules in the html header on the fly, taking into account the value of the `checkbox: false` option.

This is currently done in the `treeCreate` phase. Opening an issue was the right thing to do. The only workaround I could think of would be to create equivalent CSS yourself.

Comment: Thank you Martin, if anyone was able to assist with the workaround suggested by Martin I would highly appreciate it!